# Finding the last pay dates

Tags: java, date, calendar

I've written this simple method to give me the date of every pay period and it has ceased to work as of January first. I'm really not sure what's wrong here. It doesn't return anything.

```
   public static List<Date> getPayPeriodDatesSinceStartOfYear() {

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2);

        Calendar currentDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        currentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        int counter = 2;
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        while ((cal.getTime().compareTo((currentDate.getTime())) <= 0)) {
            dates.add(cal.getTime());
            counter += 2;
            cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, counter);
        }
        java.util.Collections.reverse(dates);
        if(dates.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO DATES, SOMETHING IS WRONG!");
        }
        return dates;
    }
```

Comment: Does the message dialog you made pop up when it runs?

Comment: Yeah, it pops up, I think what I'm doing only worked for last year in the middle of the year.

Comment: `getPayPeriodDatesSinceStartOfYear()`. As the name suggests, I think you have to run it after the 2nd week. Since, this is the first week there is not pay period yet for this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while condition is not being met, the way you have it set up `cal` is greater than `currentDate` therefore the while loop never happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2);
```

Why are you setting week to 1 and then to 2?

```
(cal.getTime().compareTo((currentDate.getTime())) <= 0)
```

See the doc for [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). It has methods like `before(Date when)` and `after(Date when)`.